# ActionScript 2 Moving an object

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, onmousedown

I have very little knowledge of ActionScript.

I have a movie clip. I want it to move along the x-axis when i press down on a button(button or movie clip) I do not know what code to use as it needs to be Action Script 2.

Is there a Tutorial or something that can accomplish this?

I have found a tutorial that moves the object around when you press a button. I am trying to get the same effect when you click down on a button:

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/xymove.htm

Thank you for any help

UPDATE

The button is called `btn` and the object that moves is `mctransparent` I have managed the folowing:

```
onClipEvent (mouseDown) {
    _root.mctransparent.onEnterFrame = function() {
        if (_root._xmouse<_root.mctransparent._x) {
            _root.mctransparent._x -= 10;
        } else {
            _root.mctransparent._x += 10;
        }
    };
}
onClipEvent (mouseUp) {
    delete _root.mctransparent.onEnterFrame;
}
```

This is on the actions panel of the btn

But when you click on the object that must move it moves. I cannot get it so the object only moves when you click and hold on the btn.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this (`btnToClick_btn` is the name of a button/movieclip and `objectToMove_mc` is a MovieClip to move):

```
// this moves objectToMove_mc 10 pixels right any time you click the button
btnToClick_btn.onRelease=function(){
   objectToMove_mc._x+=10;
}
```

`onRelease` is fired when, after clicking, you release the mouse button. You can use `onPress` if you want the object move when you press the mouse button.

You should put this code in the first frame of the Timeline AND you should have on the stage btnToClick_btn and objectToMove_mc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for the `keyPress` event, listen for the `press` or `release` event.

so you'd have

```
btn_clickMe.onPress = function() {
    //whatever moving logic you are using
}
```

or

```
btn_clickMe.onRelease = function() {
    //whatever moving logic you are using
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `btn_clickMe.` and put the code in the `btn_clickMe`'s actions panel.