# Flash Object Moves when i click on button

Tags: flash, event-handling, actionscript-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ActionScript 2 Moving an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429910/actionscript-2-moving-an-object)

I am new to AC. I have a button and a object. Is there a way for the object to move horizontally if i press down on the button in Action Script 2

Thank You for the help

Comment: Please don't repost your questions.

Answer (score 0):

in the top

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;
```

then

```
onClipEvent (mouseDown) {
    var mcX = _root.mctrapnsparent._x;
    var posX = mcX - _root._xmouse;
    new Tween(_root.mctrapnsparent,"_x",Strong.easeOut,mcX,posX,1,true);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i am very new to AC, how would a add this? Do i put it on the button's actions?